# How can I check if a Date datatype variable is in the past with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function:

```
   isAuthenticationExpired = (expirationDate: Date) => {
        var now = new Date();
        if (expirationDate - now > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Both `expirationDate` and `now` are of type Date

Typescript give me an error saying:

```
Error   3   The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 
'any', 'number' or an enum type.    

Error   4   The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 
'any', 'number' or an enum type.
```

How can I check if the date has expired as my way does not seem to work?

Comment: You cannot subtract dates directly using `-`. But you can do: `expirationDate.getTime() > now.getTime()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the integer value representation (in *ms since the unix epoch*) of the *Date* `now` and `expirationDate` using `.valueOf()`

```
var now = new Date().valueOf();
expirationDate = expirationDate.valueOf();
```

Alternatively, use `Date.now()`

Answer (score 2):

The standard JS `Date` object comparison should work - see [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=module%20My%20%0A%7B%0A%09export%20class%20Ex%20%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09public%20static%20compare(date%3A%20Date)%0A%09%09%09%3A%20boolean%0A%09%09%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09%09var%20now%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B%09%20%20%09%0A%09%20%20%09%09var%20hasExpired%20%3D%20date%20%3C%20now%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20hasExpired%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20someDates%20%3D%5B%222007-01-01%22%2C%20%222020-12-31%22%5D%3B%20%0A%0AsomeDates.forEach(%20(expDate)%20%3D%3E%0A%7B%0A%09var%20expirationDate%20%3D%20new%20Date(expDate)%3B%0A%09var%20hasExpired%20%3D%20My.Ex.compare(expirationDate)%3B%0A%0A%09var%20elm%20%3D%20document.createElement('div')%3B%0A%09elm.innerText%20%3D%20%22Expiration%20date%20%22%20%2B%20expDate%20%0A%09%09%2B%20%22%20-%20has%20expired%3A%20%22%20%2B%20hasExpired%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(elm)%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A)

```
module My 
{
    export class Ex 
    {
        public static compare(date: Date)
            : boolean
        {
            var now = new Date();       
            var hasExpired = date < now;
            return hasExpired;
        }
    }
}

var someDates =["2007-01-01", "2020-12-31"]; 

someDates.forEach( (expDate) =>
{
    var expirationDate = new Date(expDate);
    var hasExpired = My.Ex.compare(expirationDate);

    var elm = document.createElement('div');
    elm.innerText = "Expiration date " + expDate + " - has expired: " + hasExpired;    
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
});
```

More info:

- [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)
- [JavaScript Date Object](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javadate.html)